# How to avoid while() with Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, while-loop

I got from University the exercise to program a class Robot as Thread who's picking something up from an AssemblyLine (which is basically an array), waits a given amount of time and then puts it down on another AssemblyLine. You have to repeat it until the robot picks up a specific element from the array. The AssemblyLine Arrays contains PrintedBoard elements.

Here's my solution:

```
public class Robot extends Thread {

    private final AssemblyLine lineIn;
    private final AssemblyLine lineOut;
    private final long time;

    public Robot(AssemblyLine lineIn, AssemblyLine lineOut, long time) {
        this.lineIn = lineIn;
        this.lineOut = lineOut;
        this.time = time;
    }

    /**
     * When an object implementing interface <code>Runnable</code> is used
     * to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's
     * <code>run</code> method to be called in that separately executing
     * thread.
     * <p>
     * The general contract of the method <code>run</code> is that it may
     * take any action whatsoever.
     *
     * @see Thread#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintedBoard printedBoard = null;
            while (printedBoard != PrintedBoard.STOPPER) {
                printedBoard = lineIn.pickUp();
                sleep(time);
                lineOut.putDown(printedBoard);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
}
```

Like I said, the Robot Thread has an AssemblyLine lineIn which contains PrintedBoards and an lineOut which contains nothing at the beginning. The task is to pick an PrintedBoard up from the lineIn, waiting a given amount of time and then place it down on the lineOut. 
You have to repeat this until you pick up the PrintedBoard STOPPER.

I tried to do it with an while-loop. The problem is that we have to use Thread.sleep and I heard that creates massive overhead in combination with a while-loop. 
Do you know any other option I could use than while?

Comment: `" The problem is that we have to use Thread.sleep and I heard that creates massive overhead in combination with a while-loop."` -- Do you have documentation or a link for this?

Comment: Well what in particular do you mean by overhead?

Comment: Have you tried using the consumer - producer pattern?

Comment: I couldn't find it in my browser history. I think it was an answer to someones question and there was said that while in combination with sleep creates massive overhead. @Mango

Comment: I think that you may be mis-remembering something. In the future, please avoid "I heard..." type statements, and instead back up such statements with links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while-loop without sleep, also called busy waiting would consume the cpu time all the time while waiting, and so create "overhead" as you call it.

The Thread.sleep() is exactly there to avoid that. While the thread sleeps, it does not consume any cpu time. So your solution is perfectly fine.